# Global DNS / host for home network

Tags: linux, dns, routing

I'm in a situation where my Comcast cable modem will not resolve URLs hosted locally.   Essentially, if I access my website from the same network, I cannot use www.mysite.com, but instead must use 10.0.0.14 (the local IP address).   Externally, there is no issue.

I found more info on the cause of this here:   http://forums.comcast.com/t5/Home-Networking-Router-WiFi/SMCD3G-Can-t-access-web-server-from-LAN-from-Internet-OK/m-p/1754823#M55009

That said... the *simple* solution to this is to either a) access the site using the internal IP address, or b) map the URL to the local IP address using the hosts file.  I've done *b* on one of my laptops, and this does work.

*However*, I'm looking for a more robust solution to this problem, to address accessing the site with items such as an iPad that a hosts file can't be edited on.

**So the question is...**
Is there a way to setup a local DNS server that would "feed" a hosts file to all of the devices in the house?   Meaning...  can I configure the server in such a way that all requests are checked first and mapped to local addresses if needed?

Hopefully that's clear... please let me know if I can provide more detail.   I'm currently at a loss...  and mostly just frustrated that this is even an issue.

Comment: You should either [already have IPv6 or get it very shortly](http://www.comcast6.net/). That will mostly solve the problem.

Comment: Unfortunately, the modem / router does already have IPv6 running internally.  Externally, it doesn't seem to be enabled by Comcast as of yet.

Comment: Hang on...they are rolling it out in your state as we speak. :)

Answer (score 0):

The normal solution to your problem is hairpin NAT.  If your internet router supports it, you can reroute your PC's request from the public IP back to your internal subnet.

Look at your router's config options to see if you can configure NAT rules, or google your router model + "hairpin NAT".

Answer (score 0):

its not clear if your running linux or not but if you are check out dnsmasq it can be found

git clone git://thekelleys.org.uk/dnsmasq.git

or

http://www.thekelleys.org.uk/dnsmasq/dnsmasq-2.69.tar.gz

its a very simple dns and DHCP server that has a lot of features the config file is fairly self explanatory and there are lots of configs available via google